# Tiempo de respuesta excesiva entre MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo

Estoy haciendo una aplicación la cual valida ciertos datos del usuario revisando si los datos proporcionados existen en la base de datos, las respuestas de la base de datos pueden tardar al menos 3 segundos, pero haciendo las consultas directamente en la base de datos, las respuestas son inmediatas, no más de 50ms.
Tengo una clase de conexión en PHP, la cual me conecta a la base de datos con PDO y métodos estáticos para ejecutar consultas o seleccionar datos, dejaré algunos métodos de cada clase.

```
//Metodos de la clase Connection

//Método para conectarme a la base de datos
public static function connect() {
    try {
    self::$connection = new PDO(self::$server, self::$user, self::$password);
        self::$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

//Método para desconectarme
public static function disconnect() {
    try {
        self::$connection = NULL;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

//Método para seleccionar con una consulta preparada
public static function select(string $query, array $array = NULL) : PDOStatement {
    try {
        self::connect();
        $sth = self::$connection->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($array);
        return $sth;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return $sth = new PDOStatement();
    }
    finally {
        self::disconnect();
    }
}
```

Tengo otra clase la cual es para el usuario, donde se tiene métodos estáticos para hacer validaciones, los cuales me han estado problemas ya que tardan demasiado en responder, como por ejemplo, una simple consulta que me regrese un 1 si tiene una coincidencia. El código siguiente representa un método estático el cual me regresa true o false dependiendo de la respuesta de la base de datos. Cómo se mencionó anterior mente, las consultas están preparadas para evitar los ataques de SQL Injection, tal vez eso pueda influir a la lentitud de respuesta.

```
public static function usernameExist(string $username) : bool {
    $query = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username_user = :username LIMIT 1);";
    $sth = Connection::select($query, ["username" => $username]);
    $r = $sth->fetchObject();
    return $sth->rowCount() === 1 ? true : false;
}
```

Los códigos anteriores funcionan, el problema es el tiempo, ya que no hacen demasiados procesos como para tardar tanto.

Todos los archivos PHP comienzan con el siguiente código:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
header('Content-type:application/json');
```

Uso la versión de XAMPP 7.2.10 / PHP 7.2.10
Versión de MySQL 5.7.23
La aplicación está en localhost
No uso ningún depurador de código

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? ¿Qué puedo utilizar?

Saludos.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
Llegué a una conclusión, todo el código está bien, pero he estado haciendo pruebas con otra base de datos y otras funciones que ofrece PHP y al ejecutar linea por linea de código me he dado cuenta que lo que causa el problema es la siguiente linea de un nuevo ejemplo:

```
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba;charset=utf8", "root", "");
```

Comment: La base de datos está en localhost o es algún server gratuito de pruebas?

Comment: ayudaría un poco mas de info: versiones de php, mysql, sistema operativo y servidor web. las versiones de cada uno si están en distinta red/maquina

Comment: ¿Usas `XDebug` o algo similar para debuggear? Si esta extensión esta activa por defecto, es probable que afecte la performance

Comment: La información ya fue actualizada.

Comment: Podrías probar en otra carpeta escribiendo un código sencillo que haga una consulta con otra base de datos en local, solo para descartar cosas

Comment: sistema operativo?

Comment: Lo he probado en Windows 10

Comment: ok puede ser problemas de ipv6: win10 busca el "localhost" en v6 luego defaultea a v4, si estas con dhcp detras de un router q tunelea ipv6 sobre ipv4 a windows le cuesta darse cuenta, fijate en el my.cnf de comentar el bind (no es seguro para produccion pues bindea a todas las interfaces, pero te puede dar un respiro en dev local)

Comment: Por lo que entiendo en PDO la conexión se cierra cuando termina el script. Lo que te sugiero es no usar diconnect y hacer al reves, abrir la conexión y usar siempre la misma, de esa forma los 3 segundos se van con la primera conexión nada más.

Answer (score 1):

El problema puede ser que estas estableciendo la conexión cada vez que llamas a `Connection::select`.

Normalmente la conexión a la base de datos se hace una sola vez y se mantiene abierta durante toda la vida del programa.

Deberías probar hacer la conexión en el constructor del objecto y la desconexión en el destructor. Otra alternativa sería tener la conexión como una variable global.